# Obtaining width and height of an SKScene using Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I am developing a little game using Xcode 6.0.1 for iOS 8. I couldn't find anything useful on the web and I tried everything. I need an explanation to why I am getting 0.000 instead of the width and height in pixels of the device I'm developing for.

To let you know what I did:
used self.frame.size.width, self.size.width and many more.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    let testImage:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "GamePreview3.png")
    testImage.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2)
    self.addChild(testImage)

    NSLog("Width: %f", CGRectGetWidth(self.frame))
    NSLog("Height: %f", CGRectGetHeight(self.frame))

}

Width: 0.000000
Height: 0.000000
```

Is it because now with the new Xcode engine the screen size doesn't matter anymore?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the frame of the scene is always 0-sized because it has no particular "frame" (its content is not limited to a virtual frame). You should use the size property of the scene instead because that'll give you the size the scene was initialized with, which is typically (but doesn't have to be) the SKView's size.